# How to prevent user from viewing profile

Tags: 7, users

I go into `Administration>People>Permissions>User>View user profiles` and see that only admin has this permission, however while logged in as non-admin I can still see his profile when I go to  `/user`

Comment: do you mean you don't want a user to be able to view his or her own profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module and I was able to hide tabs while still giving the admin access to modify if needed.

Comment: I think that the issue is not just with tabs, we want to disable access to /user. does Tab Tamer really do this?

Answer (score 1):

There'd be a few ways you could do it, the fastest might be to create a user-profile.tpl.php and do a check for the user's group.